# Tengo problemas al enviar una imagen (que no sea PNG) convertida a un arreglo de bytes con angularJS 1.7.8 y struts2

Tags: javascript, angularjs, struts2

El problema es el siguiente...

Este el código para enviar el arreglo de bytes, mi $scope.anexos contiene objetos $scope.anexo, en el que guarda en un atributo "archivo" el arreglo de bytes "[23,1,22,34,56,67,...,etc]" de una imagen.
Todo funciona bien cuando ya no envío el $scope.anexos en la petición, los demás parametros llegan bien en el Back-End.

```
     var body2 = 'parametros=' + angular.toJson(solicitud) + '&ident=' + angular.toJson("Web") + '&jsonSoli=' + angular.toJson(nombre)
                 + '&anexos=' + angular.toJson($scope.anexos);
     return $http({
           url: raiz + 'registrarSolicitud',
           method: 'POST',
           headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
           data: body2
     }).then(response => {
           if (response.data.respuesta.ResultadoRegistro) {
           }
     });
```

Cuando estoy intentando enviar el arreglo me sale el error de net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET

Comment: Bienvenido, es importante realizar preguntas en base a el documento [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), **te sugerimos editar tu pregunta y cambiar la imagen por el código en texto (copia y pega)**. No olvides realizar el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) del sitio para conocer su funcionamiento básico, saludos.

Comment: para enviar un binario debes usar un [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/Guide/Usando_Objetos_FormData), si no todo muere